# Is there a one-line equivalent to DataContext property initialization in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a one-line equivalent to:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MyViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Something like:

```
<UserControl MyUserControl
             ...
             DataContext={SomeMarkupClassIGuess viewModel:MyViewModel}
             ...
             />
        ...
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like an `{x:Instance}` MarkupExtension.

Unfortunately, such thing does not exist.

However, it is very easy to create:

```
public class InstanceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly Type TargetType;

    public InstanceExtension(Type targetType)
    {
        this.TargetType = targetType;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(TargetType);
    }
}
```

And then use:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TextBlock DataContext="{local:Instance local:SomeClass}" Text="{Binding}"/>
</Window>
```

I have created a [UserVoice feature request](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6797655-instance-markupextension) for Microsoft to include this feature in WPF:

Please follow the link above and upvote the request so they can consider to include it in future versions of WPF.

Comment: I wonder why did you decide to create a UserVoice. Do you really think it's an essential thing?

Comment: @Tal nothing is "essential" per se. [Real programmers use butterflies](http://xkcd.com/378/), however we need to provide feedback to Microsoft about little things that need to be improved in WPF/XAML to increase productivity.